# Spark Streaming Sliding Window max and min

Tags: json, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am begineer to Spark; I am working on spark streaming use case where I receive a json messages each json message has an attribute 'value' which is double after parsing json I get a Array[Double].I want to find out max(value) and min (value) for last 15 sec with sliding window of 2 sec.
Here is my code.

```
val record = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)
val lines=record.map(_._2)

val valueDtsream:DStream[Array[Double]]=lines.map { jsonRecord => parseJson(jsonRecord) }
                            .window(Seconds(15),Seconds(2))

      valueDtsream.foreachRDD
      {
         rdd => 
           if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
           {
               //code to find min and max
           }
      }

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
valueDtsream.transform( rdd => {
  val stats = rdd.flatMap(x => x).stats
  rdd.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((stats.min, stats.max)))
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry for this silly question why do I need transform and again parallelize. Is below code is not enough to println max, min values on console for every 15 secs. valueDtsream.foreachRDD
      {
         rdd => 
           if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)
           {
             val stats = rdd.flatMap(x => x)
             println(stats.min, stats.max)
           }
      }

Comment: If you want only print you can use `foreachRDD` and drop the rest. `parallelize` because `transform` is `RDD => RDD`

Comment: Thank you I accepted this answer for my question I have 1 more issue I tried the code (without transform and parallelize) but my spark streaming job is printing values min, max every 2 sec Ideally it should only print min,max after 15 sec of window but this is not happening

Comment: You have 15 sec window with 2 sec step so this is expected. Do you want 15 sec step?

Comment: Yes I need 15 sec window